# Is any way to load entire web-page from different domain to my page?

Tags: javascript, html, applet, cross-domain, javafx

I would like to make a page where I can load other pages from different domains into it. Loaded pages should work as they work by themselves.

The reason is adding extra functionality to them.

I have tried to do it with JavaScript and iframes, but I was limited by the Same origin policy. Now I'm thinking about Java Applets/JavaFX/Apache Pivot. I have read that with digital signatures they are able to establish a connection to load a page.

My page should also take some information (title, favicon, etc) from the loaded page.

Am I right looking in this way? Or it's still impossible to do? In other case which technology is a better choice?

P.S. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a proxy that will deliver the content to your domain, and then you can manipulate the pages anyway you want (with iframes or ajax).
Let's say you make a *php* proxy named `proxy.php`:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['url']))
        echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
?>
```

The iframe's src should not be pointed to the external page (`<iframe src="somedomain.com/somepage" />`), but to your proxy that delivers the contents of that page to you : `<iframe src="proxy.php?url=somedomain.com/somepage" />`.
This would be an easy way to manage your task, although you cannot really *copy* other sites this way... you still need to take into consideration cookies, headers and other session related variables.

Comment: I can't use my server. The cookies will be lost, script on the page won't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way,  in your server side e.g. with `php` and `curl` download the page from the other domain and then ajax them into your webpage with `jQuery`.  It's like proxying pages, but now they are in you server and you can avoid granting crossdomain rules.